# What number does each color in the image represent?

Tags: visual, alphametic

This puzzle was part of a competition at my school, over two weeks ago. The school never disclosed the answer, so I'd like to check that I answered it correctly.

What number does each color in the image represent?

[image]

Comment: Editing a question to crop out the context is not proper attribution.

Comment: @Deusovi MissNature is new to SE, but [has done this before](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97501/fill-in-the-grid-such-that-no-two-digits-repeat-in-any-column-or-row).

Comment: Sorry about that i only wanted an answer to the question after i tried it myself. it a competition in my school. What did i do wrong?

Comment: Questions from other sources *must* be properly attributed, with full credit given to the question's creators (and a link directly to the source if it's online).

Comment: The three summands are rot13(bar uhaqerq rvtugl svir).

Comment: @Glorfindel Please don't answer closed questions in the comments. Questions are closed specifically so that they *cannot be answered.*

Comment: @MissNature Is this an *ongoing* competition at your school? If it is, I'm afraid it would still be off-topic even with attribution.

Comment: it's over 2 weeks ago but they never disclose the answer so i would lile to make sure i answerd it correctly 158

Comment: I've edited that information into the question and voted to re-open.

Comment: Same puzzle: https://www.republicworld.com/entertainment-news/whats-viral/only-mastermind-can-solve-this-whatsapp-puzzle-answer.html

Answer (score 1):

Let black be $x$.

The sum of the right-most column is $3x$, which produces a number ending with $x$. The only values of $x$ for which this can happen are 0 and 5.

If we exclude $x=0$ so that the colours are distinct digits, the sum at the bottom is 555.

Dividing by 3 gives you each row:

> 185

Answer (score 1):

Because

> Let $B$ be the digit represented by the black circle. The main image tells us that $B+B+B=B\pmod{10}$

so

> $2B\equiv 0\pmod {10}$, and therefore $B=0$ or $B=5$.

Then:

> because all the digits are different, $B=5$ as $B=0$ would mean everything is zero

and as

> the three addends are the same, and $\frac{555}{3}=185$, we have:
>  white is $1$, orange is $8$ and black is $5$.